# Can adding a primary key identity column solve deadlock issues?

Tags: sql-server, concurrency, primary-key, deadlock

I have a table in SQL server that is CRUD-ed concurrently by a stored procedure running simultaneously in different sessions:

`|----------------|---------|`
`|  <some columns>  |  JobGUID  |`
`|----------------|---------|`

The procedure works as follows:

1. Generate a GUID.
2. Insert some records into the shared table described above, marking them with the GUID from step 1.
3. Perform a few updates on all records from step 2.
4. Select the records from step 3 as SP output.

Every select / insert / update / delete statement in the stored procedure has a `WHERE JobGUID = @jobGUID` clause, so the procedure works only with the records it has inserted on step 2. However, sometimes when the same stored procedure runs in parallel in different connections, deadlocks occur on the shared table. Here is the deadlock graph from SQL Server Profiler:

[image: SQL Server Profiler Deadlock Graph]

Lock escalations do not occur. I tried adding `(UPDLOCK, ROWLOCK)` locking hints to all DML statements and/or wrapping the body of the procedure in a transaction and using different isolation levels, but it did not help. Still the same RID lock on the shared table.

After that I've discovered that the shared table did not have a primary key/identity column. And once I added it, deadlocks seem to have disappeared:

```
alter table <SharedTable> add ID int not null identity(1, 1) primary key clustered
```

When I remove the primary key column, the deadlocks are back. When I add it back, I cannot reproduce the deadlock anymore.

So, the question is, is a primary key identity column really able to resolve deadlocks or is it just a coincidence?

**Update:** as [@Catcall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/562459/catcall) suggests, I've tried creating a natural clustered primary key on the existing columns (without adding an identity column), but still caught the same deadlock (of course, this time it was a key lock instead of RID lock).

Comment: @MartinSmith: Yes, it has a non-unique non-clustered index.

Comment: What transaction isolation level are the SPs running at?

Comment: @DanielRenshaw: running `DBCC USEROPTIONS` in SP body shows `read committed`.

Comment: Are there any indexes that disappear when you REMOVE the primary key constraint?

Comment: @Shark: No; there's a non-unique non-clustered index on JobGUID that remains after dropping the primary key column. There are no other indexes or foreign keys (nobody else references the shared table except SP). When I add the primary key, I also declare a clustered index on it (see the alter statement in my question), which I drop manually before removing the column.

Comment: This table has *no* key without the ID column?

Comment: @Catcall: yes, it had absolutely no keys before, only one index on JobGUID column. The developers must have forgotten to add one. When I add a primary key column with a clustered index, I can no longer reproduce the deadlock.

Comment: If I were in your shoes, the next thing I'd try is altering the table and adding the natural primary key constraint.

Comment: The deadlock hints seem to say that there is an exclusive lock on one row, but another SID is trying to grab the lock on the same row.

I think it is just coincidence. Without the clustered index (or clustered PK) the table would be a heap. Thus you are basically at the mercy of the heap access as to which rows/pages get locked during each procedure execution. The clustered PK probably changes the order just enough so that you have not (yet) found a combination that gives you a deadlock.

Comment: @Catcall: Thanks for the advice, I've just tried to create a natural primary key using a combination of three existing columns and still caught a deadlock. I'll update the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best resource (still) for deadlock resolution is here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2006/09/09/deadlock-troubleshooting_2c00_-part-1.aspx.

Pt #4 says:

> Run the queries involved in the deadlock through Database Tuning
>   Advisor.  Plop the query in a Management Studio query window, change
>   db context to the correct database, right-click the query text and
>   select “Analyze Query in DTA”.  Don’t skip this step; more than half
>   of the deadlock issues we see are resolved simply by adding an
>   appropriate index so that one of the queries runs more quickly and
>   with a smaller lock footprint.  If DTA recommends indexes (it'll say
>   “Estimated Improvement: %”), create them and monitor to
>   see if the deadlock persists.  You can select “Apply Recommendations”
>   from the Action drop-down menu to create the index immediately, or
>   save the CREATE INDEX commands as a script to create them during a
>   maintenance window.  Be sure to tune each of the queries separately.

I know this doesn't "answer" the question to why necessarily, but it does show that adding indexes can change the execution in ways to make either the lock footprint smaller or execution time faster which can significantly reduce the chances of a deadlock.

Answer (score 1):

Recently I have seen this post, according to above information i hope this post will help you,

http://databaseusergroup.blogspot.com/2013/10/deadlocked-on-sql-server.html

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.