# How to avoid sql deadlock?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I am using MS-SQL 2008 and for coding am using C# in a web project.

Currently, I got stuck with sql deadlock.

I have 2 transactions, one of two is a long transaction.

When both transactions run simultaneously, deadlock occurs and short transaction will be chose to be killed automatically.

My Current solution, I am catching the exception of deadlock and redo the short transaction, it run well, just take some time.

But, I wonder that if there is any solution to avoid deadlock from the root cause?

Comment: I hope this helps . http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191242(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: try checking that your table has a primary key.

[Can adding a primary key identity column solve deadlock issues?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10737324/can-adding-a-primary-key-identity-column-solve-deadlock-issues)

Comment: What are your statements? Are they updates, inserts ??

Comment: @AzharKhorasany: is it important? In this case, both of them are insert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can't avoid deadlocks entirely, only mitigate them.

- Using [RCSI](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) isolation mode. This is basically [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control), but you have to beware that SQL Server will [still use the ANSI ACID modes on occasion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/5015/630) (DBA.SE answer). This mode stops writers blocking readers but will not help with writer-writer mutual blocks.
- Client retry logic. The classic way
- Try to do table updates in the same order eg T1 -> T2 always
- Avoid long transactions: is the client round tripping a lot and keeping the transaction open for example. You can mitigate this with stored procedures, better indexes or simply tune the query

Comment: "Client retry logic. The classic way", you mean that Try ... catch for deadlock exception and retry the killed transaction is right way, isn't it?

Comment: Hi gbn, if I have a stored procedure, and both transactions invoke that with different input, and deadlock occurs, so is there any methodology of lock to prevent deadlock?

Comment: @kidgu: create a new question and add the code, tables and indexes please. It is probably an index issue. Thanks

Comment: It is a pretty huge project, I got difficulty to extract necessary information to provide you. Is deadlock graph enough?

Comment: In this link, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/169960, my current situation is somehow similar to Example 2 or 3. In that article, the solution is enable or disable IRL (by sp_tableoption 'example1', 'insert row lock', true), but as my investigation 'insert row lock' is no longer supported, and a funny fact that Example 3 contradicted the Example 2, seems this one is also not good solution. @gbn: Is it related to Index issue which you mentioned? Thanks so much for kind sharing knowledge!

Comment: Hi gbn, by setting fillfactor of table = 50 % (and Pad index), then I reorganize all indexes of that table. --> Deadlock seems not to occur any longer. According to you, is this solution fine?

Comment: wow, no. It means you have a lot of wasted space used in memory and on-disk. And it could be a temporary fix that hides the real problem. But if it works for you, hey. Without the tables, indexes and code we can't help any more.

Comment: Hi gbn, you are correct. :( that did not work, just some test cases, it happened again. I'll create a new question with necessary information. Thanks for your advice so far.

Comment: You're welcome. Please add the link to the new question here.