# How to avoid non unique Clustered index in deadlocks

Tags: sql, indexing, sql-server-2012, database-deadlocks

I have table without primary key. But it has got non-unique clustered index on 4 columns. We are seeing this index being part of the deadlock while updating one of the non key columns in the table.
How can we avoid this? Is it better to create a primary key with 5 columns or to add a identity column? We may need to create non-clustered index as well to improve the performance once we remove the existing clustered index.

Comment: There are quite a few solutions that come to my mind (identity + non-clustered index, identity + non-clustered index with includes composite PK). The answer depends on your requirements and data structure. The only thing they have in common: you should give the table a PK. Your question can not be answered with the available information.

Answer (score 1):

The best resource (still) for deadlock resolution is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/bartd/deadlock-troubleshooting_2c00_-part-1 .

Pt #4 says:

> Run the queries involved in the deadlock through Database Tuning
> Advisor.  Plop the query in a Management Studio query window, change
> db context to the correct database, right-click the query text and
> select “Analyze Query in DTA”.  Don’t skip this step; more than half
> of the deadlock issues we see are resolved simply by adding an
> appropriate index so that one of the queries runs more quickly and
> with a smaller lock footprint.  If DTA recommends indexes (it'll say
> “Estimated Improvement: %”), create them and monitor to
> see if the deadlock persists.  You can select “Apply Recommendations”
> from the Action drop-down menu to create the index immediately, or
> save the CREATE INDEX commands as a script to create them during a
> maintenance window.  Be sure to tune each of the queries separately.

I know this doesn't "answer" the question to why necessarily, but it does show that adding indexes can change the execution in ways to make either the lock footprint smaller or execution time faster which can significantly reduce the chances of a deadlock.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10738827/7462678

Comment: Thanks LS!! I tried running DTA, I selected entire MERGE statement which is causing deadlocks  but it is showing nothing in the recommendations.

Comment: I created a new Identity column and made that primary key and clustered index. Changed the existing clustered index to non-clustered index. Now deadlock is happening on clustered index with lock-mode = X. How can we avoid this? Web service creates multiple threads and invokes the SP which has this merge statement causing the deadlock.

Comment: There's only one (simple) way to be 100% sure that you cannot get a deadlock with this procedure and that would be to add a TABLOCKX hint to the MERGE, but that would probably have a really bad impact on performance.

It is possible that adding a TABLOCK hint instead would be enough to solve the problem without having to big an effect on your performance.

Finally, you could also try adding PAGLOCK, XLOCK or both PAGLOCK and XLOCK. Again that might work and performance might not be too awful. You'll have to try it to see.